# WebBrowser control video element enter fullscreen

Tags: c#, javascript, html, webbrowser-control

In my project, I have a `WebBrowser` control with a video element and I want to insert a button that when I press it, the video element will switch to fullscreen mode.

I tried this code:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');

if (video.requestFullscreen) {
    video.requestFullscreen();
} else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    video.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

And it won't work. I read in some article that it's not possible in IE browser to make video element enter fullscreen. Is there any fix for this? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), we should be able to handle the [OnFullScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event and track the [FullScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752054%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property of `WebBrowser` control. You'd need to [access the underlying ActiveX object for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18419434/1768303). I haven't tried `FullScreen/OnFullScreen` myself, though.

**[UPDATE]** Unfortunately, [OnFullScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't get fired for `WebBrowser` when full-screen mode is entered via the native UI of the `<video>` element, **I've just verified that**. [The object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of IE `<video>` element doesn't seem to have any methods/properties/events related to full-screen mode, either. So, programmatic resizing of the `<video>` element would probably be the best option.

Comment: According [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768338(v=vs.85).aspx) the WebBrowser object ignores event  OnFullScreen.

Answer (score 2):

You could read the width and height of your viewport and set the video controls width and height to the same values. Won't go proper full screen - but will fill up the space in the browser.

Comment: +1, it appears there is no better way of doing this with IE `WebBrowser`.

Comment: @noseratio noseratio and BlackSpy would you guys mind to take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622038/how-to-change-webbrowser-fullscreen-video-mode
It's a similar one, I could not find the answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

That method requires specific prefixes to work in different browsers, in your case for IE browser you should use: `msRequestFullscreen` and `msRequestFullscreen()`

See below:

```
/* Get the element you want displayed in fullscreen mode (a video in this example): */
var video = document.getElementById("video"); 

/* When the openFullscreen() function is executed, open the video in fullscreen.
Note that we must include prefixes for different browsers, as they don't support the requestFullscreen property yet */

function openFullscreen() {
  if (video.requestFullscreen) {
    video.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    video.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    video.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

By the way if you want to exit fullscreen mode use `msExitFullscreen()` method to cancel fullscreen mode in IE browser.

See below:

```
/* Close fullscreen */
function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
```