# How to change WebBrowser fullscreen video mode?

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a c++ project with 2 `WeBBrowser` in a `TableLayoutPanel` they are set side by side, it's working fine I navigate normal but when I go to specific websites and play a video in fullscreen that sets my whole monitor to fullscreen instead of setting only the `WeBBrowser` itself, however on other websites that fits perfect in the `WeBBrowser`. Is there a way to change the way it displays fullscreen? I wanna make it display fullscreen in the `WeB​Browser` only. I think it has something to do with `Web​Browser​Base.​Active​XInstance` Property or `Web​Browser.​Document` Property. Most examples I find on the internet is for the old VB and not related to the fullscreen property.

Here's a similar question:
[WebBrowser control video element enter fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137976/webbrowser-control-video-element-enter-fullscreen)

In other examples I've seen a method to extract the element by doing:

```
HtmlElement^  object = webBrowser1->Document->GetElementById("video");
```

But I have no idea how to handle that code in order to format that video then set it back to the `WeBBrowser` with fullscreen mode fixed.

**EDIT:**

I went further and I could get the `<video>` element just from a few websites, here's my method:

```
private: System::Void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs^  e) {
        HtmlElementCollection^  videoElements = webBrowser1->Document->GetElementsByTagName("video");
        videoElements[0]->SetAttribute("style", "width: 640px; height: 480px;"); //Not sure if this is a proper way to set an attribute in this element.
    }
```

The problem is that not every website gives you access to `<video>` tag elements, so for those websites I did the following code to make sure there were indeed no `<video>` tag elements in the source:

```
System::Diagnostics::Debug::Write(webBrowser1->DocumentText);
```

Then I didn't find any `<video>` tag element in the output, only a few websites provide me that. Why? How to really get and manipulate properly `<video>` tag elements in c++?

Comment: To find all `<video` tags you might also need to look for `<iframe>` and `<frame>` elements and recuse into them.

Comment: @noseratio Thanks I looked in the page source for `<iframe>` and `<frame>` but couldn't find them. I wonder how other browsers like Chrome can find them by inspection however Chrome doesn't show any of those tags in its page source, only by inspecting each element on Chrome browser I can find `<video>` tags underneath lots of `<div>`s etc., I bet the inspection from browsers get them by JavaScript, do I really need to embed JavaScript in my c++ project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I didn't find any  tag element in the output, only a few websites provide me that. Why?

Let me make an educated guess. For some of the pages you're referring to, the DOM is built dynamically and asynchronously. Which means, those `<video>` tags might simply not be there yet.

So, you might need to have some asynchronous polling logic in place that monitors DOM changes, specifically looking for `<video>` tags.

It might not be possible to come up with a 100% working solution to cover all cases, but have a look at [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934538/1768303) which deals with this problem.